# progress bar in windows mobile 6.5

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.5

I would like to find if there is any way that i can display an indeterminate circular progress instead of horizontal bar in windows mobile 6.5.

I tried customizing but is there any method in .net compact that replaces PointF of system.drawing.

Please suggest any method to display circular progress.Tried looping it in seperate thread and changing images but didnot work.Please forward your suggestions.

Thanks in advance :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
```

Or something more elaborate?

Comment: Thanks ctacke.I was not aware of this.I searched so long and am extremely happy to find so simple solution.Could you please suggest any good tutorial or developer guide where i can get all this basics :)